# How can Rails' Activerecord table refer to itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

everyone. I have an idea to use Activerecord to implement something strange like the example below:

```
SystemInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :SystemInfo

end
```

The idea is, System A can contain System B as its child. So I will generate application's skeleton as:

```
 script/generate scaffold SystemInfo parent_id:integer name:string
```

and then, when I insert System A, I will use System A's ID as System B's parent_id (System A's parent_id will equal to 'nil'. and when I use the command like this:

```
sysA = SystemInfo.find_by_id(1) # Get System A
```

I think this is possible to get System A, and it's child, System B. Similar to:

```
sysA.childrens # Get System B and other SystemInfo which has parent_id == 1 (System A's ID)
```

Could you suggest guideline for me to implement this idea? I think this is quite common idea and we should possible to do it. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have the right idea.

```
class SystemInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'SystemInfo'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'SystemInfo', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end

s = SystemInfo.find(1)
s.children
# => [...]
s.parent
# => <SystemInfo>
```

Comment: Thank you, Erik. I have tried your solution but when I retest it in console it show something like below:

    reload!
    Reloading...
    => true
    >> SysInfo.find(:all)
    SysInfo.find(:all)
    ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): class

I use Rails 2.3.3. Could you explain me why couldn't I do like you?

Comment: I found what I have to improve. I need to use ':class_name' instead of ':class' (may be, it's from new Rails version). 

Thank you very much, Erik! I choose your answer! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Look into [`acts_as_tree`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Acts/Tree/ClassMethods.html). I used it on a project *way* back, so I'm not sure how much it has changed since then, but I think it does what you're looking for.